# Tense of a zero conditional when the main clause is in present perfect

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, conditionals

I'm not sure about the terminology so I'll just give examples.

Present simple:

> In 19th century, if you wanted to go to Japan, you had to sail.

Past simple:

> Today, if you want to go to Japan, you have to take a plane.

Present perfect:

> For the last 60 years, if you (???) to Japan, you have had to take a plane.

What would you put instead of the placeholder? "if you have wanted to go to Japan" doesn't sound right. Is this kind of a conditional possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

For the last 60 years, if you have wanted to go to Japan, you have had to take a plane.

The above is grammatically correct. It could be improved stylistically but that isn't what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

For the last 60 years, if you **wanted to go** to Japan, you **would** have had to take a plane.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this sound like the statement is no longer true?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are ***lots*** of acceptable tenses you can use for the last verb in this sentence. But the one in the *if* clause should be the simple past.

> For the last 60 years, if you wanted to go to Japan, you had to take a plane.
>   For the last 60 years, if you wanted to go to Japan, you have had to take a plane.
>   For the last 60 years, if you wanted to go to Japan, you would have had to take a plane.

(The last one taken from Andy's answer.)

The tense of the *if* clause should be simple past. You can have an *if* clause that uses the present perfect, but it would need to have a different meaning:

> If you have wanted to go to Japan for the last sixty years, but couldn't because you were afraid to fly, now is the time to volunteer to test our new experimental teleportation device.

Comment: Haha. +1 for the grammar. But that ad sounds too creepy to convince anyone to sign up.